# How to pass the DataFrame value (which is in bigint) to another DataFrame's filter condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

first get the mxdt

```
val mxdt = spark.sql("""select max(as_of_date) from db.table""")

mxdt: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [mxdt: bigint]
```

how to pass the above bigint value inside the **mxdt** df to the below query filter condition?

```
val rate = spark.table(db.table).filter(col("as_of_date") === ***mxdt***)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collect` to take the integer value:

```
val mxdt = spark.sql("""select max(as_of_date) from db.table""").collect()(0)(0)

val rate = spark.table(db.table).filter(col("as_of_date") === mxdt)
```